# Glitch in hover state when links are broken into multiple CSS columns

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout

When there is a list of links and you apply the 'column-count' CSS property to the container and you hover slightly below the last link in the first column (link 3 in the example) then the hover state will apply to the first link in the second column instead.

```css
.two-column {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2.5rem;
  width: 200px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="two-column">
                          
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 1
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 2
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 3
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 4
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 5
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I have also made a pen of the issue here [codepen](https://codepen.io/reasonmark/pen/GRmeoWa).

Edit:
You can see it happening in this GIF. Tested in Chrome 92 on macOS Big Sur, this doesn't seem to be a problem on Windows.
[image]

Comment: I'm unable reproduce it in Edge 92

Comment: Looks fine in latest Chrome.

Comment: Looks Fine in firefox 78

Comment: It's subtle but there in the Codepen in Chrome 92 but you have to hover *really* close. Frankly it's so small as to be **almost** irrelevant. Perhaps something with breaking?

Comment: No repro in either Firefox 91 or Chrome 92 in the CodePen or in the Stack Snippet, even when zoomed in 500% to try and get as close as possible.

Comment: What OS and OS version are you using? Can you reproduce in a private browsing session, or after you shut your computer down and start it back up again with a new session of Chrome? I suspect caching or first-time load only. I still can't reproduce this on Chrome-latest (92.x) in Windows 10 (or any other browser).

Comment: I think you're right @TylerH, I just tried on Windows myself and couldn't recreate the issue so it looks like this is a macOS specific issue. I can reproduce in Chrome 92.x and on macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase the vertical gap between each list item.
Here you can apply a `line-height: 20px;` to the `li` tag.

PS: Value is not specific.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Windows users can see the issue when tabbing to focus on each link.
Seems like giving the anchor tags a display of inline-block actually makes it better. Hopefully this will solve the issue on macOS aswell.

```css
.two-column {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2.5rem;
  width: 200px;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="two-column">
                          
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 1
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 2
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 3
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 4
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 5
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Chrome on macOS.

```
a:hover::after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour as before after adding this unfortunately

Comment: Remove the extra blank lines in your HTML.

Comment: Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/julainescott/pen/GREJegy).

Comment: Still the same behaviour for me on the codepen

Comment: Which version of Chrome on macOS are you testing the codepen in? 
I tested in Version 92.0.4515.159.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The problem you have is the gap between your list-items. If items are in same column, then it is not a problem at all. But in your case, the next list-item lies in the second column.

**My Understanding**

You have created only columns without rows. The content in the column can be anything like text, image, link, etc. which is divided into two columns(in your case) by the browser. As, there are no rows then you cannot apply properties like `row-gap` which only works with the `grids`.

---

### Solution

1. Change the existing structure by - either using CSS `grid` or `flex`.
2. With the existing structure - make a gap between list-items. Possibly by using either of the following CSS property on list items

- `line-height`
- `margin`
- `padding`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this bug, you can add a 1px tall element to cover the bottom of the column to prevent hover events:

```css
.two-column {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2.5rem;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Hack for Chrome column hover bug */
.two-column::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="two-column">
                          
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 1
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 2
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 3
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 4
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link 5
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```